# Error on finding the size of a char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just starting Java, and I don't understand why this code:

```
char WORDS[][] = {"jazz", "buzz", "hajj", "fuzz", "jinx", "jazzy", "fuzzy", "faffs", "fizzy", "jiffs", "jazzed", "buzzed", "jazzes", "faffed", "fizzed", "jazzing", "buzzing", "jazzier", "faffing", "fuzzing"};
char comp[] = WORDS[rand.nextInt(WORDS.length)];
char compHidden[comp.length];
```

Produces this error:

```
- Syntax error on token "[", = expected
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from int 
 to char
- Syntax error on token "]", delete this 
 token
```

All on the third line. Why is this? Is there another way I should find the length of a char array?

Comment: `char WORDS[][]` should be `String WORDS[]`

Comment: In Java, a `char[]` is not the same thing as a `String`.

Comment: A sequence of characters does not represent a character array in Java, unlike C-style strings. Also, the last line is not valid Java. The length of an array must be specified on the right side using `new` as in `char[] compHidden = new char[comp.length]`

Answer (score 0):

An assignment is expected here, like:

```
char compHidden[] = new char[comp.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WORDS` array is not instantiated as a multidimensional array, instead is instantiated as a regular `char[]` and should be declared as such.  Also the type of array should not be `char[]`, instead it should be `String[]` given the type of array assigned.

Change:

```
char WORDS[][] = {"jazz", "buzz", "hajj", "fuzz", "jinx", "jazzy", "fuzzy", "faffs", "fizzy", "jiffs", "jazzed", "buzzed", "jazzes", "faffed", "fizzed", "jazzing", "buzzing", "jazzier", "faffing", "fuzzing"};
```

to

```
String WORDS[] = {"jazz", "buzz", "hajj", "fuzz", "jinx", "jazzy", "fuzzy", "faffs", "fizzy", "jiffs", "jazzed", "buzzed", "jazzes", "faffed", "fizzed", "jazzing", "buzzing", "jazzier", "faffing", "fuzzing"};
```

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Note the in the corrected example the array is declared as `String[]`